# How to populate columns in pandas dataframe as counts of grouped occurences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have the following pandas dataframe, where col_1 can only take values `1.0` or `0.0`:

```
+-------+---------+
| score | col_a   | 
+-------+---------+
|   10  |  1.0    |
|   15  |  0.0    |
|   12  |  0.0    |
|   12  |  0.0    |
+-------+---------+
```

I would like to create the following dataframe that essentially groups by score and it then populates the counts for each score where `col_a = 1.0` or `col_a = 0.0`

```
+--------+----------|---------+
| score  |  col_a_1 | col_a_0 |
+--------+----------+---------+
| 10     |    1     |     0   |
| 15     |    0     |     1   |
| 12     |    0     |     2   |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

I understand that this is a group by op, but I am not sure how to populate the counts into new columns.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function counting occurrences of *0* and *1* in *col_a*
column in the current group of rows:

```
def cnt(grp):
    n0 = grp.col_a[grp.col_a == 0].size
    n1 = grp.col_a[grp.col_a == 1].size
    return pd.Series([n1, n0], index=['col_a_1', 'col_a_0'])
```

Then apply this function:

```
df.groupby('score', sort=False).apply(cnt).reset_index()
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
   score  col_a_1  col_a_0
0     10        1        0
1     15        0        1
2     12        0        2
```

Answer (score 0):

as your column is binary you can simply do

`col_a_1 = df.groupby('score').sum()
col_a_0 = df.groupby('score').count()- col_a_1
pd.concat([col_a_0.add_suffix('_0'), col_a_1.add_suffix('_1')], axis=1)`

[image]